# Prevent access to all php files besides one without putting files in a seperate folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this code to prevent direct access to .php files on my server:

```
#disable access to files by direct .php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule .*\.php$ 404.php [L]
```

With the piece of code above, any attempt to access a direct file on my server (for example index.php) will be denied whereas the SEO links will not be denied.

I want to make an exception to a php file on my server named "**ajax.php**". How can do it without putting files in a separate folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(?!ajax\.php).+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ 404.php [L]
```